# Position control anywhere in GroupBox for drag and drop

Tags: vb.net, winforms, drag-and-drop

I'm basically allowing users to drag and drop controls into a groupbox, which will dynamically create these controls. I want the controls to be created wherever the cursor is released. I'm assuming I need to get the coordinates or something on mouse release, then somehow pass that to the groupbox.DragDrop and dynamically create my control at those coordinates. How would I go about doing this? I already have the code to drag and drop, and my control is dynamically added to the groupbox, however, it is always added to the upper left corner of the group box

```
Private Sub GroupBox1_Enter(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles DragAndDropGroupBox.DragEnter
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
    Debug.Print("enter")
End Sub

Private Sub GroupBox_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles DragAndDropGroupBox.DragDrop
    Dim obj As dragObject = e.Data.GetData(GetType(dragObject))

    If obj.type.Equals("textbox") Then
        Debug.Print("label")
        Dim textBox As New TextBox
        textBox.Name = "TextBox" + Convert.ToString(rnd.Next)
        DragAndDropGroupBox.Controls.Add(textBox)

    ElseIf obj.type.Equals("logo") Then
    ElseIf obj.type.Equals("qrcode") Then
        Dim qrcode As New PictureBox
        qrcode.Name = "PictureBox" + Convert.ToString(rnd.Next)
        qrcode.Image = My.Resources.qr_code
        DragAndDropGroupBox.Controls.Add(qrcode)
    End If

End Sub


Private Sub idTextBoxDragHandler(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles idTextBox.MouseDown
    Dim width As Integer
    Dim height As Integer
    Dim fontSize As Integer
    Dim truncation As Integer

    Int32.TryParse(idWidth.Text, width)
    Int32.TryParse(idHeight.Text, height)
    Int32.TryParse(idFontSize.Text, fontSize)
    Int32.TryParse(idTruncation.Text, truncation)

    Dim obj As New dragObject With
    {.width = width,
     .height = height,
     .fontSize = fontSize,
     .truncation = truncation,
     .type = "textbox"}

    idTextBox.DoDragDrop(obj, DragDropEffects.Copy)

End Sub

Private Sub nameTextBoxDragHandler(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles nameTextBox.MouseDown
    Dim width As Integer
    Dim height As Integer
    Dim fontSize As Integer
    Dim truncation As Integer

    Int32.TryParse(nameWidth.Text, width)
    Int32.TryParse(nameHeight.Text, height)
    Int32.TryParse(nameFontSize.Text, fontSize)
    Int32.TryParse(nameTruncation.Text, truncation)

    Dim obj As New dragObject With
    {.width = width,
     .height = height,
     .fontSize = fontSize,
     .truncation = truncation,
     .type = "textbox"}

    idTextBox.DoDragDrop(obj, DragDropEffects.Copy)

End Sub

Private Sub descriptionTextBoxDragHandler(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles descriptionTextBox.MouseDown
    Dim width As Integer
    Dim height As Integer
    Dim fontSize As Integer
    Dim truncation As Integer

    Int32.TryParse(descriptionWidth.Text, width)
    Int32.TryParse(descriptionHeight.Text, height)
    Int32.TryParse(descriptionFontSize.Text, fontSize)
    Int32.TryParse(descriptionTruncation.Text, truncation)

    Dim obj As New dragObject With
    {.width = width,
     .height = height,
     .fontSize = fontSize,
     .truncation = truncation,
     .type = "textbox"}

    idTextBox.DoDragDrop(obj, DragDropEffects.Copy)

End Sub

Private Sub pathTextBoxDragHandler(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles pathTextBox.MouseDown
    Dim width As Integer
    Dim height As Integer
    Dim fontSize As Integer
    Dim truncation As Integer

    Int32.TryParse(pathWidth.Text, width)
    Int32.TryParse(pathHeight.Text, height)
    Int32.TryParse(pathFontSize.Text, fontSize)
    Int32.TryParse(pathTruncation.Text, truncation)

    Dim obj As New dragObject With
    {.width = width,
     .height = height,
     .fontSize = fontSize,
     .truncation = truncation,
     .type = "textbox"}

    idTextBox.DoDragDrop(obj, DragDropEffects.Copy)

End Sub

Private Sub logoDragHandler(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles logoDrag.MouseDown
    Dim width As Integer
    Dim height As Integer

    Int32.TryParse(logoWidth.Text, width)
    Int32.TryParse(logoHeight.Text, height)

    Dim obj As New dragObject With
    {.width = width,
     .height = height,
     .type = "logo"}

    idTextBox.DoDragDrop(obj, DragDropEffects.Copy)

End Sub


Private Sub QRCodeDragHandler(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles QRCodeDrag.MouseDown
    Dim width As Integer
    Dim height As Integer

    Int32.TryParse(qrCodeWidth.Text, width)
    Int32.TryParse(qrCodeHeight.Text, height)

    Dim obj As New dragObject With
    {.width = width,
     .height = height,
     .type = "qrcode"}

    QRCodeDrag.DoDragDrop(obj, DragDropEffects.Copy)
End Sub
```

Comment: Edited the post

Comment: I don't know how to get the coordinates yet, so I didn't set it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you drop your object and create your control, you need to set the location of it relative to your GroupBox interior coordinates:

```
Dim textBox As New TextBox
textBox.Name = "TextBox" + Convert.ToString(rnd.Next)
textBox.Location = DragAndDropGroupBox.PointToClient(New Point(e.X, e.Y))
DragAndDropGroupBox.Controls.Add(textBox)
```

Comment: PointToClient is what I was missing. Thanks